# Group UITableView for Selection

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableView in Group Style, and I am using it with Navigation Controller.
When a user click on the cell I am pushing to another view for a user to make selection, while all that is working fine. I want the user to be brought back to the first view when the user makes a selection. and I want to display their selection on the cell.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I might be crazy, but I thought I just heard of an app getting rejected for doing this, as it's against Apple's guidelines. Given the approval process though, if it did happen, it's possible you would get through or that it was a mistake.

Comment: maybe I didn't explain it correctly, I dont think this is against the guidelines. I am trying to due something that is done on a ebay App. When you search for an item you have a choice for type of search like auction, but it now and that is in a table view. When you click Auction it comes right back to the tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the NSUserDefaults.

```
// view controller to make selection
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *selected;
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        selected = @"Apple";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        selected = @"Microsoft";
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:selected forKey:@"SELECTED"];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Important point is you need to call [self.tableView reloadData] in viewDidAppear.

```
// view controller to show what a user selected
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Choice";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SELECTED"];

    return cell;
}
```